# How would I apply this js function to a input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function

How would I apply this js function to the input tag and return result.
here is the javascript function:

```
function checkFocus() {

if ($(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "text" || $(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "textarea") {

//Something's selected

return true;

}
```

Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" name="fname"value="">
```

My aim is to check if the input box is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery (since you have `$(document.activeElement)` in your code), you can use the `focus` listener like so:

```
$("input[type=text], input[type=textarea]").focus(() => {
    // Do something with the element
});
```

This will trigger each time you select an input box (focus it). Look at the jQuery documentation for the [focus event listener](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)